# How HackTools are harmful for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

How **HackTool:Win32/AutoKMS**, **HackTool:MSIL/AutoKMS** and **HackTool:Win64/AutoKMS** are harmful for Windows 10?

With Regards

FewL

Comment: What makes you think they are harmful? Did you see a warning somewhere? Where?

Comment: Well, anything with KMS in the name isn't going to be exactly *kosher*, is it?!? Assume a barge-pole would be needed before you touch it.

Comment: One reason I quit using AV software, I have too may tools it wants to remove all the time. And Im not taking the time to exclude them (too many) either.

Answer (score 3):

They are not *harmful* per se, but all of these tools are license cracks for Windows. If you intended them to be there, that's between you and your conscience, and you can ignore the warnings.

If you did ***not*** intend them to be there, you have several important questions to answer. Did you buy this computer from someone else? If so, you were scammed. Are you acting as IT personnel and this came up on one of the machines you control? Then it may be time to worry.

Comment: Perfect summary, Mikey... ("thumbs-up" emoji)

Comment: They are not all license cracks, I get positives on all sorts of legitimate tools.

Comment: AutoKMS is very definitely a license crack. I've never seen an illegitimate detection for that one.

Comment: They can also actually be harmful, since a malicious party, could be trying to trick you.  However, all that depends, on if you trust the source of the file.  *Most of the time somebody will complain if the file is fake and just malicious.*  If you did not download this particular file yourself, then you should consider it malicious, as it certainly isn't a Windows application you should normally trust and is used for one purpose.